# What query would get me this result?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table as follows:

```
 att1 |  att2  |  num           
------+--------+------+
 wm1    | A |    1
 wm6    | A |    3
 wm5    | B |    4
 wm7    | C |    2
 wm0    | D |    1
 wm2    | D |    2
 wm3    | D |    2
 wm4    | E |    1
```

I would like a result that gives me the maximum num for each att2. What query would give me the following table?

```
 att1 |  att2  |  num           
------+--------+------+
 wm6    | A |    3
 wm5    | B |    4
 wm7    | C |    2
 wm2    | D |    2
 wm3    | D |    2
 wm4    | E |    1
```

EDIT: I tried:

```
SELECT att2, max(num) FROM *original table* GROUP BY att2
```

but this returns:

```
 att2  |  num           
------+--------+
 | A |    3
 | B |    4
 | C |    2
 | D |    2
 | D |    2
 | E |    1
```

Comment: Before expecting an answer, you should show us what you have tried.

Comment: Sorry, edited the original post.

Comment: @3dgoo it won't let me do that in psql as att1 needs to appear in the GROUP BY or be used in an aggregate function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT t1.att1, t1.att2, t1.num 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT att2, max(num) AS max_num FROM Table1 GROUP BY att2
  ) t2 ON t1.att2=t2.att2 AND t1.num = t2.max_num
ORDER BY t1.att2, num
```

Sample [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/29370/4) using PostgreSQL 9.2.4.

Answer (score 1):

```
select att1, att2, num
from (
  select att1, 
         att2, 
         num,
         max(num) over (partition by att2) as max_num
  from the_table
) t
where num = max_num;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `SELECT att1, att2, MAX(num) as num FROM table GROUP BY att2 ORDER BY att2 ASC ;` .

Comment: Gives me the following error in psql:

     ERROR:  column "table.att1" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function